# Chrome extension in Github instead of Chrome Store

Tags: github, google-chrome-extension, hosting

I've developed a Chrome extension really useful for Google Reader fans, allow to mark individual items as read (like Gmail).

I don't want to pay US$5.00 right know, so I decided to upload my Chrome extension to Github, a free web repository.

Do you think that is going to be any problem with that? Anyone can explain me more about this please? (maybe some Chrome Extension's Developer)

Any help would be really appreciate it. Thanks!

EDIT: I uploaded [here](https://github.com/franverona/MarkAsRead-Chrome-Extension)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to maximise your extension's visibility, I'd say it's worth the $5. But if you don't care about how many people download it, and aren't too fussed about feedback and statistics, hosting it on Github is fine, too.

Some pros and cons:

**Hosting your extension on the Chrome Web Store:**

- Pros:

  - Chrome users can easily search for and find your extension
  - Autoupdating is automatic (no need to keep an Update XML Manifest file hosted somewhere)
  - Semi-customisable feature page that fits in with every other extension on the Store
  - User reviews, star ratings and install counts
- Cons:

  - Costs $5
  - Have to adhere to Google's Chrome Web Store policies

**Hosting your extension elsewhere:**

- Pros:

  - Doesn't cost $5
  - Create your own feature page how you'd like
  - Don't have to adhere to Google's Chrome Web Store policies
- Cons:

  - You have to specify and host an Update XML Manifest file to enable autoupdating functionality, and keep a PEM file safely somewhere (not a big deal but is extra work)
  - Not as many Chrome users will find your extension and give feedback (potentially, if you don't have your own community or advertising already in place)

When hosting elsewhere, you have to go through the [packaging process](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/packaging.html), then host the CRX file somewhere for users to download, and also have to (optionally) keep an [update manifest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/autoupdate.html#update_manifest) hosted somewhere and keep that up to date, so that your extension can auto-update itself for users that have installed it.

But if you're using the Chrome Web Store to host, you don't have to worry about this. You just create a normal ZIP file of your extension's files and then upload it to the Store, and you're done. The Store takes care of the auto-updating stuff for you.

Comment: I don't think extensions will sync if you self-host either.

Comment: @Chris Thank you very much. Cleary explained :)

Comment: @Tekkub what do you mean? It says here that auto-updating should work even if self-hosting: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/autoupdate.html

Comment: @Shawn He's saying that they won't sync between different computers logged into the same Google account (unlike web store extensions, they do get synced)

Comment: What if you want the extension hosted on Chrome Web Store, but want it to be open source and have others contribute? You can do both, right? (host it on Web Store and also have it on GitHub for others to contribute). I can't find any policies against this.